# My options menu is not showing on my tablayout Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-menu

I am making an app where the main activity has a App bar layout with tabs already and I want to add an options menu on the top right. I created the xml file and added the code into my java activity but it doesn't work I know it is because the theme is NoActionBar but I don't want one since I already have a bar.

So my question is:

**How do you add an options menu onto an existing AppBarLayout without adding an ActionBar?**
Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you call `setSupportActionBar(myToolbar)` ?

Comment: @Zain firstly thank you for responding, secondly no I have not called this, how would I call this (in onCreate(), and do I have to create a toolbar)? Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you share the part of layout that you use as `Toolbar` including `AppBarLayout`